# Creating a canonical question for Visa Run - does it make sense?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

I've just posted a question basically about whether or not it is allowed to reenter a country in South America twice within a short period of time.
Admittedly, this question is based on a statement, that I was never able to prove, which claims that some countries try to ban Visa Runs.

Assuming this statement was correct, I was wondering if it makes sense to create a general wiki question. That would have one answer that would list <s>all</s>... a lot of countries in the world that have applied such a limit.

If this is feasible at all. I'm not even sure how to obtain a definite answer for a particular country, much less a whole bunch of countries.

Answer (score 1):

No, such a question would be a list question and therefore inappropriate by StackExchange standards. However you may ask about whether or not visa runs are acceptable in a particular country.

Comment: I know that "list questions" are controversial but I strongly think the reason for that is that a list question does not equal a list question. Is the number of possible list items limited? Are any items on the list possibly disputed? In my book, the question I asked is not such a "list question" that we're trying to avoid. It's not even really too broad. The only issue I see is that nobody will take the effort into answering the question properly, much less care of updating it on a regular basis.